Better Way to Output This Numbers and Asterisks Pattern?
I am brand new to C and I was writing a program to output the following:
1*********
12********
...
12345678910

I've attached an image of my code (which was properly executed by my machine).
Asterisks and Number Pattern
Where am I inefficient in my code (where can I cut down on its verbosity)?

Post this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Never post "Pictures of Code", copy and paste the text of the code itself into your question and put \``con the line above your code and```` on the line below it so it formats as fixed-text with c-syntax highlighting.

Removing most of the useless comments would reduce verbosity a lot.

// include below library because we need use instruction "return" later time as
// one of many i/o = input/output posibilities offering by 
// STanDard Input Output Header (library) = STDIO.H
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  // here is start of program as main() function
            // function main() will return INTeger value for operating system
{           // open bracket of main() - here is start of the border of main()
int i=1;    // initialization "i" variable as INTeger type of numerical value
            // "i" will visible inside main brackets (visible means: scope of "i")
while (i<=10)   // "while (i<=10)" loop will start IF "i" will below or equal of "10"
    {           // open bracket of "while (i<=10)" loop ; below of this bracket and 
                // before close bracket of "while (i<=10)" loop this loop will run IF 
                // condition "(i<=10)" will true (meaning: 1 or above)
    int z=1;    // initialization "z" variable as INTeger type of numerical value
    while (z<=10)   // "while (z<=10)" loop will start IF "z" will below or equal of "10"
        {           // open bracket of "while (z<=10)" loop ; below of this bracket and 
                    // before close bracket of "while (z<=10)" loop this loop will run IF 
                    // condition "(z<=10)" will true (meaning: 1 or above)
        int z=1;    // initialization "z" variable as INTeger type of numerical value
        
                    // below is "?" statement as example if you need to shortest of "if" condition
                    // "?" works the same like "if" but readability will less
                    //
                    // "?" all line means like following (explain from left to right):
                    // before "?"   : here is condition = check if "z" is below or equal of "i"
                    // after "?"    : here (between { } brackets) is place for running code if condition of "?" will true
                    //              : true result of "?" condition means: print actual "z" value
                    // after ":"    : here (between { } brackets) is place for running code if condition of "?" will false
                    //              : false result of "?" condition means: print "*"
        (z<=i) ? { printf("%d",z) } : { printf("*"); }
        z++;        // incrementation of "z" for "while (z<=10)" loop condition
        }           // close bracket of "while (z<=10)" loop, here is end for scope of "z"
    i++;            // incrementation of "i" for "while (i<=10)" loop condition
    printf("\n");   // this will move printing position for Next line
    }           // close bracket of "while (i<=10)" loop, here is end for scope of "i"
return 0;   // return instruction will return "0" for operating system if execution of running program will come here
}           // close bracket of main() - here is end of the border of main()


this is a cleaner way of doing what you intend to do-
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

